# Angular 4: Multi-filtering table based on inputs

Tags: angular

I have a table with some data in it and I'm trying to apply filter form to filter results from the table.

This is what I tried:

1. Get data from the service. The data is an array of objects.
2. Save the data as:

`org_data` - the original, unedited data from the server

`data` - the data after filtering using the form

3. Applying filters on (ngModelChange) of the `input`.

   ```
   /** Filters from a select input */
   updateCountries(event) {
   this.campaignService.campaigns = this.campaignService.org_campaigns
     .filter((campaign) => {
   return campaign.country === event;
    });
   }

   /** Filters from a text input */
       updateField($event, field) {
         this.campaignService.campaigns = this.campaignService.org_campaigns
           .filter((campaign) => {
             return campaign[field].includes($event);
           });
       }
   ```

**The problem:**

If I'm trying to filter by country AND by field, the field filter will overwrite the country filter (all countries will be displayed).

Anyone is familiar with efficient, clear (avoid many IF's) way to perform this multi filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pipe for that (or several ones). But I will answer to you with your method :

```
option: string;
input: string;
field: string;

updateField() {
  this.data = this.org_data.filter(item => item.country === this.option && item[field].includes(this.input));
}
```

Now, you only have to bind `option` to your select, `input` to your text input, and `field` to anything that will allow you to get the field you want.

You can now call this method on both inputs.

**EDIT** Without option :

```
updateField() {
  this.data = this.org_data.filter(item => this.option ? item.country === this.option && item[field].includes(this.input) : item[field].includes(this.input));
}
```

**EDIT** With a function and 2 options :

```
updateField() {
  this.data = this.org_data.filter(item => this.checkAllOptions(item));
}

checkAllOptions(item: any) {
    let ret = false;
    ret = item[this.field].includes(this.input);
    ret = !ret && this.option1 && item.country === this.option1;
    ret = !ret && this.option2 && item.country === this.option2;
    // + Any condition you want here. 
    return ret;
}
```

With this function, if the item matches one of the 3 conditions, then it will be returned as true. You can do all the conditions you want, as you want them to be.

Comment: It will not work if there is no `this.option`. If the user decided to filter by field and didnt choose any option - it will fail. I can simply use `if` to solve it but it will produce duplicated code and don't feel ideal

Comment: Then cover the case when there's no option. I literrally copy/pasted your code and if it won't work without an option with my code, the same will happen with your actual code.

Comment: And no, it won't duplicate code, I will edit to show you

Comment: Thanks! Although I'm not sure if it's still ideal regards to scalability, since if I will decide to add another select I will have to double the condition, and if I will decide to add another 5 select filters it will blow up

Comment: You just have to create a function that returns a boolean and that has all of your conditions. Then you can reuse it, and it will be clearer to read.

Comment: Can you give an example assuming there are 2 select boxes? It will be really helpfull to understand what did you mean, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
criteria: any = {
    country: "",
    fieldKey: "",
    fieldValue: ""
};

filterCampaigns() {
    this.campaignService.campaigns = this.campaignService.org_campaigns.filter(campaign => { 
        return (campaign.country === this.criteria.country && campaign[this.criteria.fieldKey].includes(this.criteria.fieldValue));
    }
}

updateCountries(country) {
    this.criteria.country = country;
    this.filterCampaigns();
}

updateField($event, field) {
    this.criteria.fieldkey = field;
    this.criteria.fieldValue = $event;
    this.filterCampaigns();
}
```

Comment: This code relies that there is a field key and value, and the user can filter just country. If the user tried to filter country, an error appears (no fieldkey or fieldvalue)